# Converting .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7 - Facing Concurrent DbContext Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-7.0

I recently upgraded my application from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7, and I have encountered an issue related to concurrent use of DbContext.

The error message I'm receiving is: "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext."

Upon investigating the code, I found that there are several methods where await is not used within an async method, which I suspect might be related to the problem.

Interestingly, I didn't face this issue with my DbContext usage before the upgrade to .NET 7. I'm curious to know if there have been any changes in the implementation of async/await between .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 7 that could potentially cause this problem?

I acknowledge that using await within async methods is a better practice, and I am in the process of updating my code accordingly. However, I would like to understand if anyone else has experienced similar issues after migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7.

Are there any specific changes or considerations regarding async/await that I should be aware of during the migration process? Any insights or suggestions to help resolve this DbContext concurrency issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all for your support and expertise!

Comment: Do you also upgrade the EF Core package to 7? (or only the runtime?)

Comment: yes ef core is also upgraded to 7

Comment: What is the application type? Console, WPF, Winforms, ASP.NET Core API, ...?

Comment: It is webapi with unit of work pattern

Comment: M8 without code it's hard to tell you anything, but DbContext is not thread safe. So resolve this first "Upon investigating the code, I found that there are several methods where await is not used within an async method, which I suspect might be related to the problem."

Comment: webapi, ASP.NET Core? Do you also update this dependency?